# How to create a payload for requests using **kwargs?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to use **kwags to create a payload to send to an API but some parameters are optional.  This code works fine for type as if it's not present it defaults to all but I also want to add `start_date` and `end_date` then realised this would not work as the parameters are optional and I may limit the response accidentally.

```
class GenericApi():
    def __init__(self, generic_api_key):
        self.generic_api_key = generic_api_key
        self.generic_api_base_url = 'https://www.genericapi.com/api/v1/conferences/'

    # method to return GenericApi conferences
    def get_contacts(self, **kwargs):
        payload = {
            'type': kwargs.get('type', 'all'),
        }
        resp = requests.get(self.generic_api_base_url, headers={'API-KEY': self.generic_api_key}, json=payload)
        return resp.json()        

ga = GenericApi(generic_api_key='1234567890')

contact_list = ga.get_contacts(type='past')
print(json.dumps(contact_list, indent=4))
```

Would an approach like this be appropriate or am I missing a more Pythonic way?

```
def test(self, **kwargs):
    payload = {}
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        payload[key] = value
    resp = requests.get(self.generic_api_base_url, headers={'API-KEY': self.generic_api_key}, params=payload)
    return resp.json()
```

Comment: What do you want your payload to be? Are you asking how to avoid adding a `start_date` to `payload` when it is not specified in `kwargs`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes your approach would work if you are going to add default values into the default payload function (eg `payload = {"type": "all"}`) then payload would get populated with all the values that get passed in from **kargs. But if the user doesn't pass in a type parameter then it will default to `all`. Else if they do pass in one that that value stays.